# "[Errno 101] Network is unreachable" errors when querying BigQuery from AWS

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running BigQuery queries from an instance on AWS. From time to time I get the error: "[Errno 101] Network is unreachable". Is it something with my VPC configuration on AWS or a common issue when using BigQuery outside of the Google Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

BQ runs fine from AWS. Check if your server time is in sync as SSL may bishave if not.

You should check the TCP stack limit and other Linux kernel limits, maybe you reach something else, or ran out of sockets.

Occasionally some connections can drop,  usually that's every 5 on 10k successful cons.